# Event viewer - Offline downlevel migration succeeded

Tags: windows-11, event-log

So my event log has this event that happened in the future?
Looking it up didn't really help me, so I was wondering if anyone here knows if this is something to worry about.

```
Information 31/12/2023 23:59:56 Security-SPP    16394   None  
Offline downlevel migration succeeded.
Provider 
   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP 
TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2023-12-31T22:59:56.2400667Z 
Execution 
   [ ProcessID]  34568 
   [ ThreadID]  0
```